# Should I use AutoValue to store aggregated values of a collection?

Tags: meteor, meteor-collection2

I have a Comments collection and a Page collection. Comments belong to pages. Users can upvote the comments, and I want to display the aggregated sum of all the votes of the comments belonging to a page. What would be a good way to do this?

I was thinking of keeping the sum as an AutoValue inside the page collection. Would there be a way to occasionally trigger a recalculation of the AutoValue? I don't need the sum to be updated realtime, once every 5 minutes would suffice.

Or is this a bad idea? Would it be better to use a ReactiveVar in the template to do the calculation, or something else?

**Edit:** There's not much special about the setup, really. Simply a comment collection with a numeric 'votes' attribute and a pages collection with a numeric autovalue 'score' that should count the votes.
The pages:

```
Collections.Pages = new Mongo.Collection("pages");

var PageSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        min: 1
    },
    score: {
        type: Number,
        autoValue: function (doc) {
                var maxValue = 1;
                Collections.Comments.find({ pageId: doc.pageId }).map(function(mapDoc){
                    maxValue += mapDoc.votes;
                });
                return maxValue;
        }
    },
```

The comments:

```
Collections.Comments = new Mongo.Collection("comments");

var CommentSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    pageId: {
        type: String
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
        optional: true
    },
    votes: {
        type: Number,
        label: 'Total Votes',
        defaultValue: 0
    },
```

Comment: can you post code for the schemas and the publishers?

Comment: Please see edit. The publisher is nothing worth posting, as of now it simply returns a post and its comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe an alternative approach to periodic/timed recalculations might be to simply recalculate the value in one collection in response to a change in the other collection.  You said you don't *need* realtime, but I don't imagine you'd mind if it was realtime.

I had a similar challenge and used the Meteor Collection Hooks package (see https://github.com/matb33/meteor-collection-hooks).

Example:

`Collection.comments.after.update(function(userId, doc) {
   // make update to aggregated value in Collections.pages
});`

Comment: I ended up using an observer to catch collection changes (without adding any new package). Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

i did something similar: i had News items with Comments, and i wanted to track the number of comments per news item w/o having to publish all the Comments.

i chose to give News a commentCount field. i had methods for adding and removing comments, and as part of that processing, i looked up the associated News item and incremented or decremented its count.

what you're finding with your schema solution is that there's no clear way to trigger the autoValue. (it's an interesting use of autoValue, btw, i'll have to keep that in mind for future use).

so i think you're left with these choices:

1. create upvote/downvote methods for the votes. in the method handler, do the calculations for total votes and store the updated value along with post. this is similar to what i did with News/Comments.
2. as David suggested, use collection hooks to do something similar to #1. though i do use collection hooks, it's usually when i don't have a clear hook into what i want to do, it's more of a catchall, or processing driven off something i don't totally control.
3. take care of it in the publish. when you publish the Page, also look up the vote count and simply add dynamically to the publish object. Note that this won't republish the Page when the votes change, so you would lose that reactivity; you did indicate that you were ok with periodic updates.

getting that updated would be a little tricky, because you would have to force the publisher to run again. e.g. through unsubscribing and resubscribing.

of those 3, based on what i understand of your problem, i like them in the order presented. #3 feels the least viable, but i mention it in case it fits in w/ something else you're doing.